# Get userprincipal details

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

When my code is :

```
UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Username");
```

That is OK in Visual Studio and IIS.

However, when I change my code to:

```
string Name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;  
UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Name);
```

In Visual Studio it's ok, but IIS throws an error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What is happening?

Comment: Looks like you are accessing a property or calling a method on a `NULL` object.

Comment: NO  Shyju! when debug in visual studio , method get a value but on IIS return null!

Answer (score 0):

Please try again by adding < identity impersonate="true"/> this node inside the system.web of the web.config.(Remove the space before identity)

The issue was with impersonating.

Please check and revert.

Thanks

Comment: I am using <identity impersonate="true"/> in system.web , but The problem did not resolve!!